# GetX Pop to Root issue

Tags: flutter, routes, get, navigation, flutter-getx

I am running into an issue with route management using GetX on Flutter.

I have a button in my bottom navigation bar that can be pressed on from anywhere in the app. Let's call that the place the user is in when pressing on the button the root screen. Upon pressing this button, a new screen A pops up with more options in it, which when interacted with, will lead to screen B, which will lead to screen C and C ends by leading to screen D.

I have made it so that pressing on the button in the nav bar will call `Get.to(A())` and screen A pops up, and there is a back button on the top left corner of the appBar which will call `Get.back()`. My issue is that while I am on screens B, C or D, I want to implement a similar back button, which when pressed, will pop to the root screen (the screen the user was on before interacting with the button in the nav bar). The issue is that `Go.back()` in this scenario would only lead to the previous screen (D would lead to C, B would lead to A) and using `Get.offAllNamed("rootScreen")` means that I would have to store the name of the root screen and pass it all the way to D. Is there an easier way to pop to the root screen/any alternative methods using Get? Thanks!

Edit:
For now I'm calling `Get.back()` multiple times and it seems to work e.g. if I'm on Screen B I call it 2 times in a row to return to root screen, 3 times if on C, etc. If anyone knows a more efficient way, please help me out, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

store your routing in static constant values in something lile `constants.dart` in class `Constants`

that way you can use named navigation easily without passing the route path deep into your navigation stack.

Call `Get.offUntil(Constants.rootScreen);`
and this will pop your navigation stack until you reach the desired screen you want.